# The .Net core extension SeriLog filtering is not working

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, serilog

I'm using .net Core 2.0.9 and Serilog.Filters.Expressions 2.0.0.
I configured my appsettings.json to write in a log table in the Database.The data are recorded successfuly in the database but the RequestPath property is always null :

```
"Serilog": {
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Debug",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Debug"
            }
        },
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "MSSqlServer",
                "Args": {
                    "connectionString": "myconnectionString",
                    "tableName": "Log"
                }
            }
        ],
        "WriteTo:Async": {
            "Name": "Async",
            "Args": {
                "configure": [
                    {
                        "Name": "File",
                        "Args": {
                            "path": "..\\output\\log.txt",
                            "rollingInterval": "Day"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Settings.Configuration" ]
        "Filter": [
            {
                "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
                "Args": {
                    "expression": "RequestPath like '%/api/book%'"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
```

But i want to filter and save only log entries that have a specific api path. In this case, just entries that contain the api/user path in the RequestPath. But no data are saved anymore and i have no log errors, any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are working steps for me, check the difference:

1. `appsettings.json`

   ```
   "Serilog": {
       "MinimumLevel": "Information",
       "Override": {
       "Microsoft": "Critical"
       },
       "WriteTo": [
       {
           "Name": "MSSqlServer",
           "Args": {
           "connectionString": "Data Source=xx",
           "autoCreateSqlTable ": true,
           "tableName": "Logs",
           "autoCreateSqlTable": true,
           "columnOptionsSection": {
               "removeStandardColumns": [ "Properties" ],
               "customColumns": [
               {
                   "ColumnName": "Release",
                   "DataType": "varchar",
                   "DataLength": 32
               },
               {
                   "ColumnName": "RequestPath",
                   "DataType": "varchar"
               },
               {
                   "ColumnName": "ConnectionId",
                   "DataType": "varchar"
               }
               ]
           }
           }

       },
       {
           "Name": "RollingFile",
           "Args": {
           "pathFormat": "Logs/app-{Date}.txt",
           "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {Message} {UserName} {ActionName}  {NewLine} {Exception}"
           }
       }
       ],
       "Using": [ "Serilog.Settings.Configuration" ],
       "Filter": [
       {
           "Name": "ByIncludingOnly",
           "Args": {
           "expression": "RequestPath like '%/api%'"
           }
       }
       ]
   },
   ```
2. `Startup.cs`

   ```
       Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                       .ReadFrom.ConfigurationSection(Configuration.GetSection("Serilog"))
                       .CreateLogger();
   ```

For checking serilog error, adding code below:

```
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .ReadFrom.ConfigurationSection(Configuration.GetSection("Serilog"))
                        .CreateLogger();
    Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
    {
        Debug.Print(msg);
        Debugger.Break();
    });
```